# IE 8 (ONLY) crashes with JavaScript / jQuery calls to plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, crash

I'm in need of some help.

I'm building a team bio page it keeps crashing IE8 when I call jQuery plugins.

I'm not sure what is going on and can't even run the IE debugger because it crashes so hard.

Any IE8 / jQuery experts out there willing to take a look and offer some help?

[Here is the main team page.](http://bit.ly/kXckQF) Clicking through to any of the links causes the crash in IE8.

I am using:
jQuery Tagsphere, AnythingSlider, and jQuery Cycle.

Thanks in advance for any insight into this.

Comment: is it when you add any of those? or just when all of them are there?

Comment: Any of them. I've gone through and tried individually and doesn't matter.

Comment: Wow you're right.  Well, there are such things as websites that use jQuery and plugins and which *don't* make IE8 crash, so it must be something about one of those plugins, or I suppose some weird interaction.  Have you tried disabling one or more of them to see which is the culprit? (oops sorry I typed too slow :-)

Comment: I have some other jQuery going on in the main script and it doesn't crash. It's just when I use any of those three above on the page. Individually or together.

Comment: what happens if you take out all the other plugins, and just have one of those 3 troublesome plugins in the page?

Comment: Is your page by any chance a Wordpress page??

Comment: Does anyone know, would there be any reason that this could be a factor from a server change? This page / issue was not happening when developing this site on a local machine running Apache and MySQL. It was moved to a Windows server running IIS and a Microsoft MySQL server. There is no different database interaction than before, so I would say that is not a factor. But IIS vs Apache? It doesn't make sense to me that this would be a factor, but thought that I would state it anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, most notably closing iframes with IE8. Stumbled across the following code in jquery-1.6.2, which was intended to solve problems with document.domain. Some comments on the web lead me to believe this was a recent problem. Dropped back to jquery-1.4.4 and the problem was resolved.

CODE SEGMENT FROM JQUERY-1.6.2 FOLLOWS:

```
// #8138, IE may throw an exception when accessing
// a field from window.location if document.domain has been set
try {
ajaxLocation = location.href;
} catch( e ) {
// Use the href attribute of an A element
// since IE will modify it given document.location
ajaxLocation = document.createElement( "a" );
ajaxLocation.href = "";
ajaxLocation = ajaxLocation.href;
}
```